# Custom page at url change

Tags: magento-1.7, template

I'm quite new into magento and for some reason i can't seem to find a good solution!

I'm currently running a Magento shop with Ultimo Theme, great theme but there is one catch! It doesn't have a "Quickview" option...

Now, i dont want to use any extra modules but for once i'm trying to implement it my self!

It's almost working, but the only thing left to do is that i need to have a minified product page

For example if you go to http://example.com/product.html you see the whole page but as soon as you try to load http://example.com/product.html?minified=yes you should see a custom template....

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by magento event Observer

Create an event on `controller_action_layout_load_before` and add  a `new template` on this events  and

**See more at**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123483/conditionally-add-blocks-in-magento-layout
http://blog.mattstephens.co.uk/post/26827632719/adding-a-custom-layout-xml-handle-in-magento

**Step1:**`Add this at config.xml`
code is like

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <add_new_block>
                    <class>CUSTOM_MODULE/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                </add_new_block>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

**Step2:**   `create a new block`

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
'my_block_name_here',
array('template' => 'activecodeline/developer.phtml')
);
```

Study:http://inchoo.net/magento/programatically-create-magento-blocks-and-inject-them-into-layout/

**Step3:**   `then append it on event your reference block` and code

```
    public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
{   
if( Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('minified')=='yes')
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
    'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
    'my_block_name_here',
    array('template' => 'activecodeline/developer.phtml')
    );

       /* new block at content area */
    $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    }
}
```